# File nesting in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: visual-studio

Why I don't see a file-nesting icon in all projects? If I create a new WPF project on .NET 7.0 I will see a file nesting icon in Solution Explorer. However, if I create a new UWP project, I will not see a file nesting icon.

[UWP project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcRjK.png)

[image]

[WPF project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xveDd.png)

[image]

I use Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview Version 17.7.0 Preview 6.0